# Fiddler Delays HTTPS Requests

Tags: c#, httpclient, fiddler

I'm using HttpClient from C# to communicate with a web service over HTTPS.  After installing Fiddler, the initial connection to a particular HTTPS endpoint includes an additional 45 second delay.  Uninstalling Fiddler and rebooting fixes the problem.  What causes this delay?  Can it be fixed?

Comment: Installing only or installing and running it together with your c# code?

Comment: With fiddler, you can simulate "slow internet speed". That function is probably activated. For packet capture, I use always Wireshark and always works, without any problem.

Comment: Does only a single HTTPS endpoint show delay when running Fiddler? Is the other HTTPS traffic going through at normal speed?

Comment: It occurs after running Fiddler, even after closing Fiddler.  Restarting the computer corrects the problem until Fiddler is run again.

Comment: I have only observed the behavior on a single endpoint.  Other HTTPS traffic seems to go through at normal speed.

Comment: That is weird. What is in Fiddler Log for that request?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as unique.